# Displaying 2 WebViews together in one Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, android-linearlayout, android-dialog

I currently have a WebView as the "contentView" for a Dialog. This works perfectly.
Now I want to display two Webviews side-by-side in a single Dialog.

I tried putting them together in a LinearLayout, and using that LinearLayout as the "contentView" for the dialog. But it doesn't work.

This is my code, the result is just an Empty dialog (height of approx. one line)
PS. The activity is fixed on landscape mode.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);           
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    WebView webView1 = new WebView(this);
    webView1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
    webView1.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    webView1.loadUrl("http://www.url1.com");
    linearLayout.addView(webView1);

    WebView webView2 = new WebView(this);
    webView2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
    webView2.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webView2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView2.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    webView2.loadUrl("http://www.url2.com");
    linearLayout.addView(webView2);


    dialog.setContentView(linearLayout);
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: use wrap_content for the height of the linearlayout

Comment: Just checked your code. It's working for me. What is `context`?

Comment: It's the context passed trough the method (showVerkeersInformatie) opening this dialog.
btnVerkeersInfo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   { 
    showVerkeersInformatie(SpeedMeterActivity.this);    
   }
  });

Comment: So "SpeedMeterActivity.this" is passed as a parameter, which is indicated by "context" in the code above

Comment: Hmm, I see.
Probably, I should instantiate LinearLayout with "context" instead of "this"

Comment: Probably. Same with webviews. May be it is the reason of issue.

Comment: I still get the same result... Strange. 
The Dialog shows the two webviews correctly on your machine?

Comment: Yes. Dialog shows two webviews correctly. I changed only one thing: `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);`

Answer (score 0):

Use getApplicationContext instead of context for instantiating the dialog..this works sometimes...